# VS2008 WinForm property color picker dialog has changed

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64

I have just upgraded to a machine running Windows 7-64bit.

Now in VS2008, when I go to set the BackColor property of a control on a WinForm, the usual color picker (Custom/Web/System) has been replaced with just a simple dropdown list containing the names of the System and Web colors.

Is this just a quirk in my installation, or does this happen in all Win7-64 environments?

**EDIT :** Must have been VS throwing a fit - after restarting, the color picker dialog came back!

Comment: I've got similar problems, Win7 x64 is leaking GDI resources somewhere.  I can't see where from Taskmgr.exe, I have to restart it once a week or so.

Comment: the classic TechSupport, __have you tried rebooting your machine sir??__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have VS2008 on Win 7 64bit, and my color picker is the same as before:

[image]

Comment: Dammit! That means somethings gone screwy with my installation :(  Thanks.